# String Number Addition Java

Tags: java

This is my second week learning Java and I'm trying to implement some functions that I saw in the book I'm studying with.

With the first function I wanted to represent an integer as an array of integer digits so that I can bypass the range of integer values.

For example:

---

### 1st Function

Input : integerInput(123456)

Output : integerString[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

### 2nd function

Input : stringInput[] = {123456}

Output : integerString[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

### 3rd function:

*(I want to add the 2 integer string values as in like normal addition)*

Input : integerString1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6} integerString2[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

Output : [2,4,6,9,1,2]

---

This is what I have so far, it is full of mistakes and all i could get is an empty output. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

```
public class tryingOut{
    
    public static int[] integerToNumberArray(int value) {
        String temp = Integer.toString(value);
        int[] list = new int[temp.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            list[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
        return list;
    }
    
    public static boolean isNumeric(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            int d = Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public static int[] stringToNumberArray(String value) {
        
        boolean checkNumeric = isNumeric(value);
        
        if (checkNumeric = false) {
            return null;
        } else {
            String[] items = value.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("\\s", "").split(",");
            
            int[] results = new int[items.length];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                try {
                    results[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
    
    public static int[] addNumberArrays(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
        int[] result = null;
        
        return result;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int test1 = 19;
        int test2 = 823;
        int[] list1 = integerToNumberArray(test1);
        int[] list2 = integerToNumberArray(test2);
        
        //  stringToNumberArray(test1);
        //  stringToNumberArray(test2);
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: "_full of mistakes and all i could get is an empty output_" You should tell us the specifics about at least 1 of those errors and also which line of code were you expecting to print some output?

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger?

Comment: Please limit your post to only one of your function examples and include the errors you get with it

Comment: By the way, to work with very large integer numbers, use the [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) class built into Java.

Comment: This is not difficult but more so than you may realize.  For example, you need to handle carry over from one addition to the next.  So since 6 + 6 is 12 you need to put 2 in the array location and carry 1 over to the next addition. This also means that if index 0 adds to where a carry is generated, you need to decide how to handle it since you can't carry to location of -1.  So you either  copy the array or declare overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Programming with JAVA. Firstly, I appreciate your enthusiasm for programming and the efforts you made.

As mentioned in the comments by [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque) you can achieve this by [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html). However, I like your interest for trying this yourself and therefore I will try to share a code below with as much description I can provide to make it understable to you.

---

To point out few mistakes in your original code:

1. You do not need to handle `null` separtely with `if-condition` for your method `isNumeric(String value)` becaause the `try-catch` block will automatically handle it for you.
2. For `stringToNumberArray(String value)` method you do not need to use the `String.split` and also it was quite unclear what you did there in line `String[] items = ...`

---

Full code:

```
public class PlayingWithInt {
    
    public static boolean isNumeric(String value) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // This handles both null and other non int values so we don't need an extra condition to check for null
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    // Assuming argument value is "123456"
    public static int[] stringToNumberArray(String value) {
        if (isNumeric(value)) { // We generally don't write `== true` or `== false` with boolean values
            char[] valueAsCharArray = value.toCharArray(); // valueAsCharArray = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'}
            int[] valueAsIntArray = new int[valueAsCharArray.length]; // valueAsIntArray = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
            
            for (int i = 0; i < valueAsCharArray.length; i++) {
                valueAsIntArray[i] = valueAsCharArray[i] - '0';
            }
            return valueAsIntArray; // valueAsCharArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
        }
        return null; // Null will be returned if the value is not numeric
    }
    
    // Assuming argument value is {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}
    public static int[] stringToNumberArray(String[] value) {
        int[] valueAsIntArray = new int[value.length]; // valueAsIntArray = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            valueAsIntArray[i] = value[i].charAt(0) - '0';
        }
        return valueAsIntArray; // valueAsCharArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    }
    
    // Let's say value is 123456
    public static int[] integerToNumberArray(int value) {
        String valueAsString = Integer.toString(value); // valueAsString = "123456"
        return stringToNumberArray(valueAsString); // We are using our already built method that does the same thing.
    }
    
    public static int[] addNumberArrays(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
        int maxLength;
        if (a1.length > a2.length) maxLength = a1.length;
        else maxLength = a2.length;
        
        int[] result = new int[maxLength + 1];
        
        int i = a1.length - 1; // Index iterator for a1
        int j = a2.length - 1; // Index iterator for a2
        int k = result.length - 1; // Index iterator for result
        int carry = 0; // carry to handle case when the sum of two digits more than deci/ ten (10)
        
        while (i >= 0 && j >= 0) {
            int sum = a1[i] + a2[j] + carry;
            result[k] = sum % 10;
            carry = sum / 10;
            i--;
            j--;
            k--;
        }
        
        // If a1 has more digits than a2
        while (i >= 0) {
            int sum = a1[i] + carry;
            result[k] = sum % 10;
            carry = sum / 10;
            i--;
            k--;
        }
        
        // If a2 has more digits than a1
        while (j >= 0) {
            int sum = a2[j] + carry;
            result[k] = sum % 10;
            carry = sum / 10;
            j--;
            k--;
        }

        result[0] = carry;
    
        return result;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int test1 = 123456;
        int test2 = 123456;
        int[] num1 = integerToNumberArray(test1);
        int[] num2 = integerToNumberArray(test2);
        int[] result = addNumberArrays(num1, num2);
        
        for (int i : result) System.out.print(i); // This is known as enhanced-for-loop or for-each-loop
        
        System.out.println();        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0246912
```

---

### Additional Input and Output:

**Example 1**

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int test1 = 19;
    int test2 = 823;
    int[] num1 = integerToNumberArray(test1);
    int[] num2 = integerToNumberArray(test2);
    int[] result = addNumberArrays(num1, num2);
    
    for (int i : result) System.out.print(i); // This is known as enhanced-for-loop or for-each-loop
    
    System.out.println();        
}
```

Output:

```
0842
```

**Example 2**

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int test1 = 823;
    int test2 = 19;
    int[] num1 = integerToNumberArray(test1);
    int[] num2 = integerToNumberArray(test2);
    int[] result = addNumberArrays(num1, num2);
    
    for (int i : result) System.out.print(i); // This is known as enhanced-for-loop or for-each-loop
    
    System.out.println();        
}
```

Output:

```
0842
```

**Example 3**

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int test1 = 999;
    int test2 = 999;
    int[] num1 = integerToNumberArray(test1);
    int[] num2 = integerToNumberArray(test2);
    int[] result = addNumberArrays(num1, num2);
    
    for (int i : result) System.out.print(i); // This is known as enhanced-for-loop or for-each-loop
    
    System.out.println();        
}
```

Output:

```
1998
```

---

### References:

1. [String.toCharArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray())
2. [Enhanced for-loop |OR| For-Each Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html)
3. [Integer.parseInt(String value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. It made every concept that I was looking very clear.

Comment: You are welcome. And do not forget to up vote if you find this helpful.

`Happy Coding`